# How to show only filtered record count (number of returned data from search, num_rows() ) in codeigniter, jTable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-jtable

How to show only filtered record count (number of returned data from search, num_rows() ) in codeigniter, jTable.

As now is showing all the row number from database no matter how many search result i have.
I dont know how to solve this. All i want is to show only the filtered data record count number. Can anyone help me?

Here is my view.php:

```
<div class="JtableCrud">
<div class="filtering">
    <form class="searchbox_1">
        Country Name: <input type="text" class="search_1" name="country_name" id="country_name" />
        City Name: <input type="text" class="search_1" name="capital_city" id="capital_city" />
        Date from <input class="search_1" type="date" name="from_date" id="from_date"/>
        Date to <input class="search_1" type="date" value = "<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>"  name="to_date" id="to_date"/>
        <center><button  class="submit_1" type="submit" id="LoadRecordsButton">Search</button>
            <input class ="submit_1" type="reset" value="Clear fields!"></center>

    </form>
</div>
<div id="countryTable"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#countryTable').jtable({
        title: 'Country\'s',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'country_name ASC',
                selecting: true,
                multiselect: true,
                selectingCheckboxes: true,
                selectOnRowClick: true,
                actions: {
                        listAction:   'get_country',
                        createAction: 'create_country',
                        updateAction: 'update_country',
                        deleteAction: 'delete_country'
                },
                fields: {
                    country_id: {
                    key: true,
                        list: false
                    },
                        country_name: {
                        title: 'Country Name'
                        },
                        country_code: {
                        title: 'Country Code'
                        },
                        surface_area: {
                        title: 'Surface Area (m<sup>2</sup>)',
                        width: '13%'
                        },
                        continent_name: {
                        title: 'Continent Name'
                        },
                        continent: {
                        title: 'Continent Code'
                        },
                        population: {
                        title: 'Population'
                        },
                        capital_city: {
                        title: 'Capital City'
                        },
                        record_date: {
                        title: 'Record Date',
                                type: 'date',
                                displayFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                                create: false,
                                edit: false,
                                sorting: false
                        }
                },
    formCreated: function (event, data) {
    data.form.find('input[name="country_name"]').addClass('validate[required]');
            data.form.find('input[name="country_code"]').addClass('validate[required], custom[onlyLetterSp][maxSize[2]]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="surface_area"]').addClass('validate[required,custom[number]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="continent_name"]').addClass('validate[required]');
            data.form.find('input[name="continent"]').addClass('validate[required], custom[onlyLetterSp][maxSize[2]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="population"]').addClass('validate[required], custom[number]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="capital_city"]').addClass('validate[required]');
            data.form.validationEngine();
    },
    formSubmitting: function (event, data) {
    return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
    },
    formClosed: function (event, data) {
    data.form.validationEngine('hide');
            data.form.validationEngine('detach');
    }
        });

                $('#country_name').autocomplete({
                    source: 'list_country',
                    minLength: 0,
                    scroll: true,
                    autoFocus: true
                }).focus(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", "")
                        .autocomplete( "widget" )
                        .addClass( "country_field" );
            });

             $('#capital_city').autocomplete({
                source: 'list_city',
                minLength: 0,
                scroll: true,
                autoFocus: true
            }).focus(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", "")
                        .autocomplete( "widget" )
                        .addClass( "country_field" );
            });

        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#countryTable').jtable('load', {
                country_name: $('#country_name').val(),
                capital_city: $('#capital_city').val(),
                from_date: $('#from_date').val(),
                to_date: $('#to_date').val()
            });

        });

        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();

    });

</script>
</div>
```

Here is my model.php:

```
<?php

class Country_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_country($country_name,$from_date,$to_date,$capital_city)       {

    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS country_id, country_code, country_name, surface_area,
        continent_name, continent, population, capital_city, record_date
        FROM  country 
        WHERE (deleted = 0) 
        AND (country_name LIKE '%" .$this->db->escape_like_str($country_name) . "%' ) "
     . "AND (capital_city LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str($capital_city) . "%' ) "
     . "AND (record_date BETWEEN'" . $from_date . "' AND date_add('" . $to_date . "', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) "
     . "ORDER BY " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtSorting") . " 
        LIMIT " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtStartIndex") . "," . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtPageSize") . ";");

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($result->result() as $row) {

        $rows[] = $row;

    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Here is my controller.php

```
 <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class country_tas extends CI_Controller {

public function get_country() {

    if (empty($this->input->post('to_date'))){
        $to_date = date('Y-m-d');
    }else {
        $to_date = $this->input->post('to_date');           
    }

    $country_name = $this->input->post('country_name');
    $capital_city = $this->input->post('capital_city');
    $from_date = $this->input->post('from_date');
    $this->load->model('Country_model');
    $rows = $this->Country_model->get_country($country_name,$from_date,$to_date,$capital_city);
    $num_rows = $this->db->count_all_results('country');
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $num_rows;
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);

}
```

Comment: you will have to fire one more query to get number of records with your filter conditions but without passing start and end limit, use that num_rows as total count of filtered records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it!

> To obtain this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward.

I added to my SELECT query "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" and then i created this function:

```
 public function record_count(){

     $num_rows = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() count;')->row()->count;

     return $num_rows;       
}
```

and i called it on my controller:

```
 $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $this->Country_model->record_count();
```

That solved my problem. If you have a better solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_rows = $this->db->count_all_results('country');

//this will fetch all records from country table.

//replace it with this:
$num_rows  = count($rows);
```

Comment: Yea but its not good because it shows only the row number of the current page. and when i have more result it shows only how many records i have on one page. not the total number.

Comment: And because of that i dont have paging in my table.

Comment: you should add some detail about your answer.